How to reverse an array and get the first element with LINQ
references is an array of custom type ChaptersReferenceBase[]
I would like to reverse the array before getting the first reference based on some state.
   public ChaptersReferenceBase GetAvailableReference() // This works but doesn't reverse the array
    {
        foreach (var item in references)
        {
             if (item.State == StorageSlot.Available) return item;
        }
        return null;
    }

   public ChaptersReferenceBase GetAvailableReference() // This works but doesn't reverse the array
    {
        return references.First(reference => reference.State == StorageSlot.Available);
    }

   public ChaptersReferenceBase GetAvailableReference() // Throws nullReferenceException
    {
        Array.Reverse(references);
        return references.First(reference => reference.State == StorageSlot.Available);
    }

   public ChaptersReferenceBase GetAvailableReference() // Throws nullReferenceException
    {
        return references.Reverse().First(reference => reference.State == StorageSlot.Available);
    }

Why does this happen in my Unity unit test? How can I reverse the array and get the right element.

references.LastOrDefault(reference => reference.State == StorageSlot.Available);

The second two approaches, which you claim throw a NullReferenceException, do in fact work and do not throw an exception: https://dotnetfiddle.net/jSpDbp

@canton7 could this be a bug in Unity’s test runner then? I was surprised that my test was failing because of the reverse operation.

@KonstantinMakarov  references.LastOrDefault(reference => reference.State == StorageSlot.Available);  Throws NullReference, too, in the Unity unit test (not in the assert but in the code.)

@Ando, try: references.LastOrDefault(reference => reference != null && reference.State == StorageSlot.Available); or references.Where(reference => reference != null).LastOrDefault(reference => reference.State == StorageSlot.Available);

when you foreach by first () , it's mean your first element not null maybe data like this:
[obj,null,null,null]

and find obj in first . so not throw NullReferenceException.
but and when you reverse array like this :
[null,null,null,obj]

now, first element is null , so thorw NullReferenceException now.
it's mean NullReferenceException thorw at reference.State

Wouldn't LINQ handle the nulls, tho? Thanks for the answer. I think your assumption is correct but I don't understand why that should be a problem.

@Ando, the problem occurs when accessing the property of an element that is missing, i.e. here: reference.State (null.State)

@Ando No, LINQ not handle null. you can check by self.
